# Assign nmap result to an array in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I made a bash script to insert the result of `nmap` command to an array. The script is working on bash 4.3.30, but it does not work when I try to run it on bash 4.4.12. It looks like the array is empty or it just have the first value.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a IP_ARRAY
NMAP_OUTPUT=`nmap -sL $1 | grep "Nmap scan report" | awk '{print $NF}'`
read -a IP_ARRAY <<< $NMAP_OUTPUT
printf '%s\n' "${IP_ARRAY[@]}"
```

With bash 4.3, the values of the string `NMAP_OUTPUT` are well copied to the array `IP_ARRAY`. The the other version not and I don't find the error.

The string NMAP_OUTPUT looks like:

```
10.0.0.0 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.3 10.0.0.4 10.0.0.5 10.0.0.6 10.0.0.7 10.0.0.8 10.0.0.9 10.0.0.10
```

Instead of using my code above, this code works:

```
 IP_ARRAY=(${NMAP_OUTPUT})
```

I would like to understand with my previous code is working on one version and not in the other one.

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script has multiple issues which could be fixed. It could be done very simply minimizing a number of steps.

1. You are using `NMAP_OUTPUT` as a variable. The `bash` shell does support arrays which you can use to store a list. Also independent entries present in a variable's context undergo  Word-Splitting done by the shell. The consequence of that is, if a entry has spaces in-between, it will be tough to identify if it is a separate word or part of a whole word.
2. Storing the command output to a variable and later parsing to an array is round about way. You can directly pass the output to an array
3. Using `grep` and `awk` together is not needed, `awk` can do whatever `grep` can
4. Always quote the shell variable and array expansions. Never use unquoted expansion in your results (like in `<<< $NMAP_OUTPUT`). It could have adverse affects in case of words containing spaces.
5. Always use lower case variable names for user-defined functions/variables and array names.

---

#### Use [`mapfile`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/mapfile) built-in

Version of bash v4.0 on-wards provides options `mapfile`/`readarray` to directly read from a file or output of command.

All your script needs is

```
mapfile -t nmapOutput < <(nmap -sL "$1" | awk '/Nmap scan report/{print $NF}')
printf '%s\n' "${nmapOutput[@]}"
```

---

There is nothing I could infer why your script didn't work between the versions of `bash` you've indicated. I was able to run your script on the given input on `bash 4.4.12`

But the crux of the problem seems to be using variables and arrays interchangeably in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you're trying to do this the hard way.
why not simply:

```
IP_ARRAY=( `nmap -sL 127.1/29 | grep "Nmap scan report" | awk '{print $NF}'` )
```